# Call extension function nested inside an object, from outside that object

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

How do I call an extension function that's nested inside an object from outside that object?

Here is an example:

```
package test

object Example {
    fun String.exampleExtension() {
    }
}

fun test(str: String) {
    str.exampleExtension() // Doesn't work. How can I use that extension function?
}
```

As far as I can tell this isn't possible, but I'm not sure, so I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Unless the extension is depending on global state stored in your (singleton) Example object, there's no reason why it shouldn't be a top level function. No real need to nest it in Example.

Comment: I can see why you might think that, however I've run into other use cases where it is useful. i.e. when using a stateless DSL like https://github.com/ScottPierce/kotlin-html, and you want to split your DSL usage into re-usable functions, I'm finding an approach like this a necessity, otherwise I end up with naming collisions for private functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can do this.

The simplest is:

```
fun test(str: String) {
    with (Example) {
        str.exampleExtension()
    }
}
```

The other thing you can do is manually import the extension function. As of Kotlin 1.3.41, the compiler doesn't offer this via code completion, and you have to manually request it.

```
import test.Example.exampleExtension

fun test(str: String) {
    str.exampleExtension() // Works now because of the import
}
```

I created a Kotlin bug to try and fix this, and have the auto-complete suggest this as an import: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33221